# VSTO custom ribbon icon image quality

Tags: image, vsto, ribbon-control

Afternoon all,

I'm building a custom ribbon in VB .NET for Excel 2013/6 and have made images that show up looking like they are hand drawn with a crayon.

My images are 50x50 pixel PNGs and set to small size.

I note here that there are recommended dimensions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316921(v=vs.85).aspx

Are the images required to be exactly those pixel dimensions and if not, any ideas why they show up not sharp?

I have also tried different starting file types (PNG, JPEG, BMP) which didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

For the Office Ribbon UI the accepted sizes are 32x32 or 16x16. The former will give higher resolution.

The optimal file format is *.png.

The link you provide is for Windows Ribbon, not the Office Ribbon, which is why the result you're getting is not what you expect.